# Replacing superflous paragraph breaks with space using Word wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, wildcards

I'm not very familiar with Word (2010 in this case) Wildcards language and hit a small obstacle.
I have a file that underwent OCR and as a result has a lot of paragraph breaks mid-paragraph as it resembles the layout of the source. However, in word these broken up sentences zre a pain to work with.

I used the search term

```
[a-z]^13[a-z]
```

to search for all the paragraph breaks that are surrounded by lowercase letters, and it works find.

My problem is that I have no idea what syntax to use in the Replace With field to replace the paragraph symbol with a space without deleting/changing the surrounding characters.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your search term slightly.  Place parentheses around the wildcards, that causes the character which matches the wildcard to be remembered.  Then the replacement string needs to use a backslash to re-use the matched character.  Thus:

Find:  `([a-z])^13([a-z])`

Replace With:  `\1^32\2`

This should work, replacing each paragraph break with a space.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly, and as a bonus helped me understand the overall language syntax and usage a little better.